# loop through .rds files from directory and convert to data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to loop through a list containing the file_path to all .rds files in a folder.

I can easily load one .rds file and then convert it to a data frame as shown below. However, the issue is how to first load all files and subsequently convert the rds. files to separate dataframes. I suspect a for-loop using file_path as input is necessary.

```
user_x <- readRDS("/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/thesis/data/VK_Data/75315975_VK_user.rds") # load data

user_x_df <- as.data.frame(user_x) # convert to dataframe
```

```
file_path <- list.files(".../VK_Data", pattern="*.rds", full.names=TRUE)

print(file_path)
  [1] "/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/thesis/data/VK_Data/103656622_VK_user.rds"
  [2] "/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/thesis/data/VK_Data/11226063_VK_user.rds" 
  [3] "/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/thesis/data/VK_Data/112552215_VK_user.rds"
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have the right idea. You can make a for-loop to do this. Since you have your vector of file paths, you could do something like I do below. Note that I don't know how you want your data frames named, but this will read everything in.

```
library(tidyverse)

## counting how many files in your directory
file_number <- 1 

for (file in file_path) {
   name <- paste0("df_", file_number) ## getting a new name ready
   x <- readRDS(file) ## reading in the file
   assign(name, x) ## assigning the data the name we created two lines up
   file_number <- file_number + 1 
}
```

This gives you as many data frames named `df_*` as there are files in your `file_path` vector.

You could then append all of them together (assuming they have the same column names and column types) using this:

```
full_data <- mget(ls(pattern = "^df_")) %>%
   reduce(bind_rows)
```

In the above code, the `ls(pattern = "^df_")` line returns a list of all of the data frames in your global environment that start with "df". The `mget` function will grab these for you, and the `reduce(bind_rows)` should append them all together.